# removing item from list on href click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a ViewBag to pass a List into a View. I am then displaying each string in the list one by one using a foreach over the List. I need to allow a user to remove entries from the list by clicking on the entry e.g. if a user clicks one of the strings then it will disappear. What is the most straightforward way to do this?

ViewBag.FlagList: 
`ViewBag.FlagList = listStrLineElements;`

**cshtml:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <hr />
    <p><strong>Flagged Questions</strong></p>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.FLagList)
    {
        <div>
            @item
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can have a button, that has a click event, such that when the user clicks on an entry, the value is passed on as param to the click function, and you can call the built-in function for List to remove that entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `parent` by parentNode and remove `itself`.

```
<div onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)"> @item  </div>
```

```js
function onDelete(elm, id) {
    // Do something with id
    console.log(id)
    elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm)
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Click to remove</strong></p>
<div onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
    1
</div>
<div onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
    2
</div>
<div onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
    3
</div>
<div onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
    4
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)"> href sample</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)"> href sample 2</a>
</div>

<div onclick="onDelete(this, '1221')">
    onDelete Function sample
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot

Comment: is there anything i can do to stop the page jumping back to the top after i remove an entry?

Comment: `href="javascript: void 0"`

Comment: give fix div height, like min height

Comment: i have tried `<div href="javascript: void 0" style="height:auto">` although it still jumps. would it be possible to edit your code so it does not jump after an element is removed please? It would also be nice if the div still got smaller as elements are removed (maybe this is not possible)

Comment: href="javascript: void 0" wont work here.. give default `style="min-height: 100px"`